# How to create Multiple-Column Indexes efficiently?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Let's say I've coded.

```
create index use_index on tbl_nm (col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5);
```

would use_index be used in

```
select * from tbl_nm where col2="something", col5 = "something", col3="something");
```

Also, we should have created index by ordering the most unique on the left and the most common on the right. right?

And if I would like to order the query result should I add that column into the index too?

Comment: Recommend reading through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html. There is also a good presentation here on index usage https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The index should be at least refs used in common queries first followed by columns search by range.

So in your example here `col2` and `col3` will be use this index. but because there is no col4, the searching for `col5` won't be as quick. i.e. all `col4` items with `col2` and `col3` matching "something" will be scanned for a matching `col5`.

If you where searching for `col4` rather than `col5`, it would be a binary search to the required item.

Use `EXPLAIN {query}` to show what the index usage is.

Consideration of most unique vs least in the order of the index isn't really considered.